# How can we set tables relations in SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I have SQL Server Express 2008. How can I set a table's relations in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run the [ALTER TABLE statements necessary](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/08/sql-server-%E2%80%93-2008-creating-primary-key-foreign-key-and-default-constraint/) to add the foreign key relationships between tables either via:

- [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170207.aspx)
- Management Studio

  - [2008 Express download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en)
  - [2005 Express download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 5):

Just like with any other database:

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [foreign_key_name] 
FOREIGN KEY [local_column] 
REFERENCES [foreign_table] ([foreign_column]) 
ON UPDATE RESTRICT 
ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

SQL Server Management Studio gives you a graphical UI to do the same thing through a click-and-point interface, but internally, it executes queries like these.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install SQL Server Management Studio or run the SQL to create the FKs yourself.

Comment: I have to install SQL Server Management Studio 2008 ? or I can install 2005 version ?

Comment: What ever version of DB server you have, your SSMS should match

Comment: Actually, SSMS 2008 works fine with previous versions (back to 2000 at least).

Comment: Thats true, but it doesn't work inversly. SSMS 2005 will not work for SQL Server 2008 for example.